# Website is working on port 8080 but not on root '/'

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, centos7, digital-ocean

My website is working on domain name test.in:8080 but it is not working on test.in.
Below is my nginx.conf file.

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  digitaloceantwo.25o2.in;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in:8080";
        }

}
```

It is also works on ip-address:8080 but not on 'digitaloceantwo.25o2.in'.

Comment: did you run `nginx -t` to make sure the config is valid and `nginx` reload or restart to make sure the config is loaded? Is there a firewall?

Comment: I did run nginx -t. it gave me following output.
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

There is no firewall.

Comment: Is the config file enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Use  https://nginxconfig.io/ to help you for config file

You just need a simple reverse proxy

Comment: try to simplify config like this : `server {
  listen 80;
 server_name http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in:8080;}`

Comment: server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass         "http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in:8080";
        }
}

i am trying the same but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

try adding these below root /usr/share/nginx/html;

```
index index.html;
location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

then run :

```
- nginx -t (if it is ok), run :
-service nginx reload
-service nginx restart
```

Comment: It is showing me nginx welcome page " Welcome to nginx on Fedora! ".

Comment: Hey, glad to know that. Your nginx is running, Can you give me the whole configuration or have a check across the path to the index.html file. Also can you brief me the message it is showing?

Comment: Also what nginx config file are you configuring? Is this default?

Comment: server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  digitaloceantwo.25o2.in;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass         "http://digitaloceantwo.25o2.in:8080";
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        
    }

Comment: Yes , i am using default nginx configuration.

Comment: And what's the error message when you hit it, is it 404?

Comment: it showing me nginx error!
The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: Well, bro, its all about proxy here, if you are not trying to proxy to a html file, make sure that the server which you are proxying to is a valid process running at a particular port. And the process's port and the port which nginx is occupying should not be same if they are on same machines.